# Почему при клике создается 2 блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему при клике появляется не один блок, а два? Думаю всё дело в obj.after($('.b-rewiews__other-comment').detach()); так как когда её удаляю, то блок один, но зато скрипт работает на всей странице, где есть ссылка .b-rewiews__more-answer,а с этой строчкой открывается только в одном. Чем заменить её можно?

```
$('.b-rewiews__more-answer').on('click', function() {
    var obj = $(this).parents('.b-rewiews__rewiew-block');
    // Insert Ajax with data
    obj.after($('.b-rewiews__other-comment').detach());
    $('.b-rewiews__other-comment').slideDown();
    $(window).scrollTop($('.b-rewiews__other-comment').offset().top - 160);
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ov4b1v6e/

Пример:

```js
$('.b-rewiews__more-answer').on('click', function() {
  var obj = $(this).parents('.b-rewiews__rewiew-block');
  // Insert Ajax with data
  obj.after($('.b-rewiews__other-comment').detach());
  $('.b-rewiews__other-comment').slideDown();
  $(window).scrollTop($('.b-rewiews__other-comment').offset().top - 160);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.b-rewiews__other-comment {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-block b-rewiews__rewiew-block--answer comment row">
  <div class="b-rewiews__photo col-md-1 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="b-rewiews__photo-line">
      <img src="images/content/avatar-review.jpg" alt="" title="" class="b-rewiews__image" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-rewiews__comment col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-10">
    <div class="b-rewiews__review b-rewiews__review--answer">
      <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-name row">
        <div class="b-rewiews__name col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Лариса Коркина</div>
        <div class="b-rewiews__date b-rewiews__date--answer col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 date">22.10.2015 17:21</div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-text"><span class="b-rewiews__name-answer">Александра, </span>
        <p>на вашем месте я была бы аккуратнее. Обратите внимание на раздел с мужским ассортиментом. Мне кажется, что данное женское кольцо для слесаря — не очень удачная идея.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-answer row">
        <div class="b-rewiews__helpful col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12"><span class="b-rewiews__review-helpful">Отзыв полезен?</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer-yes">Да</a><span class="b-rewiews__number-yes">170</span><span>/</span>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer-no">Нет</a><span class="b-rewiews__number-no"> 0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer">Ответить</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__more-answer">Другие ответы</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b-rewiews__other-comment">
  <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-block b-rewiews__rewiew-block--answer row">
    <div class="b-rewiews__photo col-md-1 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="b-rewiews__photo-line b-rewiews__photo-line--comment">
        <img src="images/content/avatar-review.jpg" alt="" title="" class="b-rewiews__image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b-rewiews__comment col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-10">
      <div class="b-rewiews__review b-rewiews__review--answer">
        <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-name row">
          <div class="b-rewiews__name col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Александра Малафеева</div>
          <div class="b-rewiews__date b-rewiews__date--answer col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 date">22.10.2015 17:21</div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-text"><span class="b-rewiews__name-answer">Лариса, </span>
          <p>мой муж любит выделяться из толпы, поэтому ассортимент из мужской коллекции ему 100% не понравится, а мне в свою очередь хочется его порадовать.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-answer row">
          <div class="b-rewiews__helpful col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12"><span class="b-rewiews__review-helpful">Отзыв полезен?</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer-yes">Да</a><span class="b-rewiews__number-yes">2000</span><span>/</span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer-no">Нет</a><span class="b-rewiews__number-no"> 0</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer">Ответить</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-block b-rewiews__rewiew-block--answer row">
    <div class="b-rewiews__photo col-md-1 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="b-rewiews__photo-line b-rewiews__photo-line--comment">
        <img src="images/content/avatar-review.jpg" alt="" title="" class="b-rewiews__image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b-rewiews__comment col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-10">
      <div class="b-rewiews__review b-rewiews__review--answer">
        <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-name row">
          <div class="b-rewiews__name col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Александра Малафеева</div>
          <div class="b-rewiews__date b-rewiews__date--answer col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 date">22.10.2015 17:21</div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-text"><span class="b-rewiews__name-answer">Лариса, </span>
          <p>мой муж любит выделяться из толпы, поэтому ассортимент из мужской коллекции ему 100% не понравится, а мне в свою очередь хочется его порадовать.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="b-rewiews__rewiew-answer row">
          <div class="b-rewiews__helpful col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12"><span class="b-rewiews__review-helpful">Отзыв полезен?</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer-yes">Да</a><span class="b-rewiews__number-yes">2000</span><span>/</span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer-no">Нет</a><span class="b-rewiews__number-no"> 0</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-rewiews__answer">Ответить</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="b-rewiews__close-answer">Скрыть ответы</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте разметку html к которой это все применяется

Comment: добавил ссылку на песочницу, правда там код совсем не работает, а стили добавлять очень долго придется. Но суть в том, что он создает последний блок в 2-х экземплярах (это который с ссылкой на закрытие блока)

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение про добавление сниппета!